# Firebase Analytics Debug View for the Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to use Firebase Analytics **Debug View** on the web? If so, how? The web is not documented, but also not specifically excluded.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: Did you try it? Is something not working the way you expect?  If the console isn't working the way you expect, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I quickly browsed through the [documentation guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview), and [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.analytics) and indeed don't see any way to enable debug mode for a web client. You might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

*Update (20191008)*: the functionality to have debug mode in web clients does exist, but there is no public API yet. I will update here when a public API to enable debug mode is available.

*Update (20200210)*: the best I've found so far is to use the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) Chrome extension.

Comment: any update on this ? Try to add web analytics events and not seeing them in debug view. I don't even see the events in my network request/dev tools and I'm copying the examples directly from the firebase docs

Comment: I said 5 days ago saying that I'd update once there's a public API. I haven't updates since, so... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯    You can also keep an eye on the release notes of the JavaScript SDK yourself: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: Sorry Frank didn't realized that was only 5 days ago :) ... As a ~workaround, the Streamview seems to be working for Web analytics in firebase.

Comment: Thanks Will I can also confirm there seems to be no way to view web analytics events in debugview but I can see them in streamview.

Comment: Something I learnt since, the Google Analytics Debugger extension for Chrome is a great way to see these events too.

Answer (score 4):

I tried successfully to Debug by using instructions (for Web) at https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview?authuser=0#enabling_debug_mode.

After installing  Google Analytics Debugger, there appears an icon of this extension, next to address bar. This icon helps on enable the extension for the page.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Not sure why your answer got downvoted, as it is actually a really good way to see what analytics events a page is creating.

Comment: Google Analytics Debugger now seems to be the recommended way of enabling debug for web for firebase analytics. When it's enabled the events also show up on DebugView in the firebase console. This was really helpful for me. Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen and user2136211

Comment: it's horrible to have to put an extension in, but this works.